# Flutter daemon doesnt start

Tags: flutter, git, dart

I started vs code and got the error flutter daemon failed to start. I opened the log and the error was that git was not found in path even though i have added git to path. Here is the log

```
[6:54:12 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat with args ["daemon"]
[6:54:12 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  in C:\flutter
[6:54:12 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code","FLUTTER_ROOT":"C:\\flutter"}}
[6:54:12 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info]     PID: 14948
[6:54:12 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["language-server","--protocol=lsp","--client-id=VS-Code","--client-version=3.74.0"]
[6:54:12 PM] [Analyzer] [Info]     PID: 21988
[6:54:12 PM] [General] [Info] Returning cached results for project search
[6:54:12 PM] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
[6:54:12 PM] [DevTools] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["devtools","--machine","--try-ports","10","--allow-embedding"]
[6:54:12 PM] [DevTools] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code","FLUTTER_ROOT":"C:\\flutter"}}
[6:54:12 PM] [DevTools] [Info]     PID: 14948
[6:54:12 PM] [General] [Info] Version last used for Pub is 3.1.5 (3.1.0), current is 3.1.5 (3.1.0)
[6:54:12 PM] [General] [Info] Found 0 folders requiring "pub get" or "pub upgrade":
[6:54:12 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 6429
[6:54:12 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":14948,"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code","version":"1.83.1"},"locale":"en","rootPath":"c:\\Windows\\System32\\learningdart","rootUri":"file:///C%3A/Windows/System32/learningdart","capabilities":{"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"workspaceEdit":{"documentChanges":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"],"failureHandling":"textOnlyTransactional","normalizesLineEndings":true,"changeAnnotationSupport":{"groupsO…
[6:54:12 PM] [General] [Info] Loaded 20000 package names from vscode-userdata:/c%3A/Users/preda/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/dart-code.dart-code/package_cache.json
[6:54:12 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] <== Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

Comment: Try to execute `where git` command to see if you get any output. If you see the path you added to PATH, try to re-open the terminal or maybe even restart your PC - sometimes the changes are applied only after restart